# facebook: get all the login and logout date and time

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get all the time date and time of the login and logout of a user?

Because currently I need need to make a timesheet for this one.

Thank you,

Comment: you can only do this with your own app, but not with facebook login/logout. would be a major security/privacy problem if you would just be able to read the login/logout times of a user.

Comment: are there any other way doing this work around?

Comment: no, and as i said: it would be a major security/privacy problem. why would anyone want to know the login/logout times of a user in a serious way?

Comment: because i'm planning to build something big and those kinds of data will be my bullets.

Thank you luschn for your answer